# NodeJS - Import order

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

I do not understand how nodejs resolves import statements. I constantly get the cannot import before initialization error.

For example, I have a init module, which exports an async function and a couple of constants that it creates.

```js
import init, { DATA_VALIDATION_POOL, QUEUE_POOL, IS_REPLAY_POOL } from './init.js';
```

and then `app.js` waits for the init function to run. `init.js` itself has imports as well, and some of them resolve and some of them fail. I do not understand why some fail and some import properly.

In this example, everything to the point of importing from `./utils/pool.js` is working fine, but for whatever reason, it cannot import the contents of `./utils/dash.js`.

`./utils/dash.js` doesn't import anything from `../init.js`

#### init.js

```js
...
// CREATE POOLS
...
export const QUEUE_POOL = createPool('QUEUE_POOL');

// EMOJI INTERACTIONS
...
registerEmojiInteraction(QUEUE_POOL, {
  ...
  onAdd: goToPrevPage,
});

const init = async () => {
  ...
  await createCoaches(allCoachIds);
};

import { rankEmojis, raceEmojis, vsRaceEmojis } from './Emojis.js';
import { registerEmojiInteraction, onAddHelper } from './utils/emojiInteraction.js';
import { createPool } from './utils/pool.js';
import {
  finishedCoachingStudent,
  goToPrevPage,
  selectStudent,
  goToNextPage,
} from './utils/dash.js';
import { createCoaches } from './utils/coach.js';

export default init;
```

Comment: @etarhan all `utility/<filename>.js` modules are just collections of functions, they never call or define any constants except for the functions. Aka nothing except for `export const <functionName> = () => {}` for the entire file.

Comment: @etarhan import statements are hoisted